# How use skype across ruby (any gem?)

Tags: ruby, skype

I need comunicate a rails ap with skype, more specific, I need than(previously aprovation) a user can call other user using skype and keep both id private, is that possible?, thank so much!!!

Comment: I think he wants to allow his users to call each other anonymously over skype without logging in to skype.

Comment: This question needs further clarification. Is this a web application? Or are you trying to get ruby to open skype? To many unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

**I think** this is impossible, as to make a skype call you have to provide an email, alias and/or number. If you really want anonimity you should think about web-based video chats, or code your own.